# Creating a Column to return value in 3months

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am just starting off in R and I am stuck on a fairly simple problem. I have the following test dataset:

[image]

```
T1 <- data.frame(Make = c("Nissan","Nissan","Nissan","Nissan","Nissan","Nissan","Nissan",
             "FORD","FORD","FORD","FORD","FORD","FORD"),
    YearMonth = c("Apr-13","May-13","Jun-13","Jul-13","Aug-13","Sep-13","Oct-13","Apr-16","May-16",
    "Jun-16","Jul-16","Aug-16","Sep-16")),
    Value = c(10000,9500,8000,7500,6000,5000,4000,12000,11000,10000,8000,7000,5000))
```

I would like to create two extra columns to return "value in 3months" and "final value" so something like:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do a `lead` by `n = 2` after grouping

```
library(dplyr)
T1 %>%
    group_by(Make) %>% 
    mutate(Value_in_3_months = lead(Value, 2), FinalValue = last(Value))
```

---

If we want to create an index base on the 'YearMonth' column, convert to `yearmon` class and do a `match` with the original column

```
library(zoo)
T1 %>%
  mutate(YearMonth = as.yearmon(YearMonth, "%b-%y")) %>% 
  group_by(Make) %>% 
  mutate(Valuein3 = Value[match(YearMonth + 2/12, YearMonth)])
```

Comment: Thanks! That does work, but what if I want to make use of the "YearMonth" column instead of lead. I tried the following: mutate(valuein3 = Value[YearMonth+3/12]) but it doesnt seem to work. Any ideas why?

Comment: Thank you! Works amazingly well!